# How do I get my world back?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I was playing Minecraft Tuesday night and all was good. I turned on my Xbox 360 to play on Wednesday morning and there was an update you had to do before playing,  and it would log you out (basically would not let you play until you did the update). After the update went through the icon for my world is there to play but when you go to it and get in there all my work is gone and it is a brand new place. What happened? Can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a dupe question, but in short, unless you have made a backup copy of your world to a USB stick or the cloud service, your world is gone.

This appears to be a common (but seemingly random) problem after many of the Minecraft updates. The only cases where I've read of people recovering their world is if they had a back up and they roll-back the update. Restore the backup and try the update again.

Sorry for the bad news.